# tizk well formed grid on a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

How to draw a well formed grid absolutely positioned on a page with tikz?

Each of the following pages has some problem.  Is there a rounding error somewhere?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\date{}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

% wrong join on left, not closed on right
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm,step=8.0mm,thin,black] ($(current page.south west) + (17mm, 17mm)$) grid ($(current page.south west) + (17mm,17mm) + (176mm,264mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak

\thispagestyle{empty}

% wrong join on left, not closed on right
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm,step=8.0mm,thin,black] ($(current page.south west) + (17mm, 17mm)$) grid ($(current page.south west) + (17mm,17mm) + (176mm,264mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak

\thispagestyle{empty}

% wrong join on left, wrong join on right
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm,step=8.0mm,thin,black] ($(current page.south west) + (17mm, 17mm)$) grid ($(current page.south west) + (17mm,17mm) + (177mm,265mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An even number of intervals will produce and odd number of lines.

Comment: There is also this link:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201560/using-pstricks-i-need-to-created-the-following-grid-sheet-which-fits-well-with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perfect grid:

[image]

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\date{}
\title{}
\begin{document} 

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, thin]
\coordinate (o) at ($(current page.south west) + (17mm, 17mm)$);
\foreach \x in {0,...,22}
  \draw ([xshift=8mm*\x]o) -- ++(0mm,8mm*33);
\foreach \y in {0,...,33}
  \draw ([yshift=8mm*\y]o) -- ++(8mm*22,0mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the [TikZ-pgf manual](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (sec. 14.8 The Grid Operation) page 154, says about this issue:

> due to rounding errors, the "last"
>   lines of a grid may be omitted. In
>   this case, you have to add an epsilon
>   to the corner points

So, you shouldn't rely on TikZ grids when high accuracy is required. This may change in a future version (I hope!).

**EDIT:**

Here is a manual fix if you insist on using the grids (I don't recommend):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[step=8.0mm, thin,black] ($(current page.south west) + (17.29mm, 17.1mm)$) grid ($(current page.south west) + (193.30mm,281.11mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```